# How to fix puppet installation of ifupdown2 so that networking comes back up (or doesn't go down)?

Tags: puppet, debian-bullseye, ifupdown

I have puppet code which automatically installs ifupdown2 on newly provisioned physical servers (along with all other new host configuration).  (This is Debian 11 Bullseye.)

However, nearly all of the configuration *fails*, that's applied after this package is installed, because networking goes down on installation of ifupdown2, and so files can't be downloaded from the puppet server or from apt repos, etc.

Not only that, but Puppet can't self-recover from this.  The box has to be handled out of band (i.e. console, ipmi, etc.) to either `ifup -a` or just reboot so networking will come back up.

I found this is a known issue for ifupdown2 installation: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1703008.html

The recommendation there is:

> For provisioning systems like ansible, puppet etc., I recommend that you
> set it up to push a script to the node that basically executes the
> equivalent of "apt-get install ifupdown2 && systemctl restart
> networking" using nohup or something else to make it not fail if the
> network itself is down.

My current relevant puppet stanza is just:

```
    package { "ifupdown2":
      ensure => 'latest',
    }
```

How should I fix this so the rest of the puppet config will apply correctly, i.e. so that networking will come up as part of applying that one resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the recommendation you have found, you could just restart the networking service after the package installation. This approach requires that the `service{'networking':}` is also managed by Puppet.

```
package { "ifupdown2":
  ensure => 'latest',
  notify => Service['networking'],
}
```

Another method could be using an [`exec` resource](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/types/exec.html):

```
package { "ifupdown2":
  ensure => 'latest',
  notify => Exec['start-networking'],
}

exec { 'start-networking':
  refreshonly => true,
  command     => [
    '/usr/bin/systemctl', 
    'start', 
    'networking'
  ],
}
```

Likewise, you could use an `exec` to run the `ifup -a` .

These might still cause some resources running right after the package update to fail, but will fix the networking for the next Puppet run. If this is not acceptable, you would have to abandon using the `package` resource type for this update altogether. You could replace it with a script that does the update & service restart before ensuring any other resources.

Comment: Thanks!  I successfully used the exec approach, but I went with "start" rather than "restart" (I suggested an edit to the answer) because with package version set to "latest" there would otherwise be a networking restart any time a new ifupdown2 package version is released, which would be destructive.  (It's only removal of ifupdown prior to ifupdown2 installation that brings down networking.)